# RTL Text/StyledText on OSX

Tags: java, macos, swt, right-to-left

I have a problem with displaying and editing text in my application of rtl text on osx. (written from right-to-left like arabic or hebrew instead of left-to-right like most other languages)

On windows, the `StyledText` component lets you switch between rtl and ltr with ctrl+right or left shift (also a rtl language has to be installed i think)
On osx, there is the shortcut ctrl+cmd+left/right arrow which works in some applications (ie. TextEdit), but not in the StyledText or any other swt component.
I have searched google for a solution, but cant find it anywhere.

I did find [some](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=261270) [bugreports](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=64413), but these did not help me to find a solution.

Does anyone here knows a method of aligning text right-to-left in an eclipse plugin application on osx?

Comment: Well, the first bug report you posted seems to be pretty clear: Just changing the writing direction isn't supported by SWT and mirroring the whole thing isn't supported by OSX. I'm afraid you're out of luck here. Did you try creating the `StyledText` with `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT` as the style?

Comment: Yes. This does not make any difference.

Comment: For others facing this problem:
You have to initialize the `StyledText` (or `Label`) with `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT | SWT.RIGHT` as style.
This also only has effect when initializing, so not with `setOrientation()`. On Windows, only `SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT` has to be used.